# Existence of bounded linear functional

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm currently studying functional analysis and in the lecture there was a step I do not understand:

Namely, if $x^*$ is a bounded linear functional from $X$ to $\mathbf{R}$ and $A : X \rightarrow Y$ a bounded linear functional between $\mathbf{R}$-vector-spaces, then $\Vert x^*(x) \Vert \leq C \Vert A x \Vert$ for $C  > 0$ implies that there exists a bounded linear functional $\phi: Im A \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ such that $\phi \circ A \equiv x^*$. Can someone explain to me, what is going on here?

I already thought that it had to do with Hahn-Banach, however I did not find anything in my notes that could match this.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide $X$ by $\ker A$ and let $\tilde{A}$ and $\tilde{x}$ be the quotient maps from $X/\ker A$ to $Y$ and $\mathbb{R}$, respectively (possible since we know that $\ker x^*\supset\ker A$. Let $\phi=\tilde{x}\circ \tilde{A}^{-1}$. This certainly satisfies the required equation, verify that it also is continuous.